# NullPointerException on JPA query

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, nullpointerexception

As the title says I'm getting a null pointer exception when I call a method in my data repository to retrieve some data. 
I'm making an API with the Spring Boot framework using JPA+Hibernate

I've checked if the method parameters are null or empty but all the parameters are good. I also tried change the query but I'm getting the same nullPointerException on execution time.

```xml
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.10.5</jjwt.version>
    </properties>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

This is a part of my pom.xml

This old query works:

```java
@Query("SELECT d as d from Data d, File f where d.contextSource.id=?1 and d.param.id=?2 and d.file.id = f.id and f.creationDate between ?3 and ?4 and f.labSystem.id=?5 and f.sampleType.id=?6 order by d.file.creationDate asc")
    List<Data> findParamData(Long contextSourceId, Long paramId, java.util.Date start, java.util.Date end, Long labSystemId, Long sampleTypeId);
```

But the new one withouth the date where doesn't works:

```java
@Query("SELECT d as d from Data d, File f where d.contextSource.id=?1 and d.param.id=?2 and d.file.id = f.id and f.labSystem.id=?3 and f.sampleType.id=?4 order by d.file.creationDate asc")
    List<Data> findPreviousDataEntry(Long contextSourceid, Long paramId, Long labSystemId, Long sampleTypeId);
```

My Data.java class:

```java
package eu.qcloud.data;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import eu.qcloud.contextSource.ContextSource;
import eu.qcloud.file.File;
import eu.qcloud.param.Param;
import eu.qcloud.threshold.InstrumentStatus;

@Entity
@Table(name="data")
public class Data {

    @JsonIgnore
    @EmbeddedId
    private DataId dataId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="paramId",insertable=false, updatable= false)
    private Param param;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="contextSourceId",insertable=false, updatable= false)
    private ContextSource contextSource;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fileId",insertable=false, updatable= false)
    private File file;

    private Float value;

    private Float calculatedValue;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(columnDefinition="varchar(255) default 'OK'")
    private InstrumentStatus nonConformityStatus = InstrumentStatus.OK;

    public Float getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Float value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Data() {}

    public Data(Param param, ContextSource contextSource, File file) {
        this.param = param;
        this.contextSource = contextSource;
        this.file = file;
    }

    public DataId getDataId() {
        return dataId;
    }

    public void setDataId(DataId dataId) {
        this.dataId = dataId;
    }

    public Param getParam() {
        return param;
    }

    public void setParam(Param param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

    public ContextSource getContextSource() {
        return contextSource;
    }

    public void setContextSource(ContextSource contextSource) {
        this.contextSource = contextSource;
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public Float getCalculatedValue() {
        if(calculatedValue == null) {
            return Float.NaN;
        }
        return calculatedValue;
    }

    public void setCalculatedValue(Float calculatedValue) {
        this.calculatedValue = calculatedValue;
    }

    public InstrumentStatus getNonConformityStatus() {
        return nonConformityStatus;
    }

    public void setNonConformityStatus(InstrumentStatus nonConformityStatus) {
        this.nonConformityStatus = nonConformityStatus;
    }


}
```

Here the call to the method:

```java
Long noseya = new Long(8);
        System.out.println("CS ID: " + this.getContextSourceId());
        System.out.println("LS ID: " + this.getLabSystemId());
        System.out.println("ST ID: " + this.getSampleTypeId());
        System.out.println("PARAm ID: " + noseya);
        List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();
      data.addAll(dataRepository.findPreviousDataEntry(getContextSourceId(), noseya, getLabSystemId(), getSampleTypeId()));
        for (Data hola: data) {
            System.out.println(hola.getValue());
        }
```

And finally the exception trace:

```
RetentionTimeDriftProcessor
CS ID: 1
LS ID: 3
ST ID: 1
PARAm ID: 8
2019-04-12 16:01:44.919 ERROR 10993 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at eu.qcloud.data.processor.processors.RetentionTimeDriftProcessor.processData(RetentionTimeDriftProcessor.java:81) ~[classes/:na]
    at eu.qcloud.data.DataService.calculateValueFromGuideSet(DataService.java:515) ~[classes/:na]
    at eu.qcloud.data.DataService.insertDataFromPipeline(DataService.java:384) ~[classes/:na]
    at eu.qcloud.data.DataController.insertDataFromPipeline(DataController.java:162) ~[classes/:na]
    at eu.qcloud.data.DataController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f95bfd3e.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at eu.qcloud.data.DataController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bc23b4bc.insertDataFromPipeline(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
```

I don't have any idea about what I'm doing wrong. I know that I'm not the firsts that encounters a NullPointerException but I tried everything answered in another questions.
Thanks you.